Tomcat 9.0 Deployment: SAXParserFactory not found
I'm using Tomcat v9.0.87 with Java 1.8.0_412.
The Tomcat starts very well, just with root and manager application.
If I deploy two war-files, the whole Tomcat crashes.
>  09-Jul-2024 10:49:34.899 SCHWERWIEGEND \[main\] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Error deploying web application directory \[/web/tomcat/tomcat-9.0/webapps/manager\]
> javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider \__redirected.\__SAXParserFactory not found
> at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:200)
> at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:152)
> at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:232)
> at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:126)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.getFactory(Digester.java:556)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.getParser(Digester.java:708)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.getXMLReader(Digester.java:880)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1519)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1135)
> at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1888)
> ...
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: \__redirected/\__SAXParserFactory
> at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
> at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
> at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.getProviderClass(FactoryFinder.java:124)
> at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:188)
> 42 more

What can I do to solve the problem?
